# Risks of shared Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, wifi

What are the risks when using a shared Wi-Fi in a group home? I am not the administrator. My device is an iPhone 6s Plus. The OS is iOS 9.2.

Comment: Instead of adding a "thank you" comment, please upvote answers you consider useful. Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more details about how the site works.

Comment: @patrix Casting upvotes requires 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

The question is, do you trust the person that maintains the wireless network? Do you trust the other people that are using the wireless network? There are all kinds of risks when you connect to someone else's network. For example, [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), [DNS hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking), etc.

I'm not saying you shouldn't use the shared Wi-Fi in a group home, but just be aware there are risks connecting to any network that you don't control.

A security researcher, Troy Hunt, recently published a blog article on a related subject. He is explaining why he doesn't allow guests to connect to his home Wi-Fi, but the risks he mentions hopefully explain better some of the things that can go wrong with Wi-Fi networks. [No, you can’t join my Wi-Fi network](http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/12/no-you-cant-join-my-wifi-network.html)

Comment: Interestingly, if done properly, an HTTPS site can *almost* completely guard against man-in-the-middle attacks. However sites that actually go the lengths of doing that would be far and very few between.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the shared Wi-Fi **at home** there isn't any risk (if you trust the persons in your home).

The only thing is that when connected, you are sharing the total bandwidth with the other users and therefore the single speed in terms of download and upload will be lower for each user.